# How do see find number of lines changed per file in git log

Tags: git

The title says it all. When using `git log` is it possible to print changed line count per file?

This would be helpful because sometimes a single commit can be quite large, containing hundreds of files. And I quickly want to get down to the meaty bits instead of going through all files one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Use the `--stat` option:

```
git log --stat
```

Comment: Try `--numstat` as alternative.

Comment: Would that take into account that a line change on git is a line removal and a line add?